# Laravel get class name of related model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In my Laravel application I have an `Faq` model.  An `Faq` model can contain many `Product` models, so the `Faq` class contains the following function:

```
class Faq extends Eloquent{ 
    public function products(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('Product');
    }
}
```

In a controller, I would like to be able to retrieve the class name that defines the relationship.  For example, if I have an `Faq` object, like this:

```
$faq = new Faq();
```

How can I determine the class name of the relationship, which in this case would be `Product`.  Currently I am able to do it like this:

```
$className = get_class($faq->products()->get()->first());
```

However, I'm wondering if there is a way to accomplish this same thing without having to actually run a query.

Answer (score 185, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to get related model without query:

```
$className = get_class($faq->products()->getRelated());
```

It will work for all relations.

This will return full name with namespace. In case you want just base name use:

```
// laravel helper:
$baseClass = class_basename($className);

// generic solution
$reflection = new ReflectionClass($className);
$reflection->getShortName();
```

Comment: getRelated is a great find! Previously I was using $className = get_class($faq->products()->getQuery()->getModel());