# How to get a relationshipped model by a model and FK in Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, model, foreign-keys

So, what I'm trying to obtain is a related model class given an other model class and a column name which is a FK.

Suppose I have a model named 'Event' and a model named 'ShowStatus' and the Event model has 'show_type_id' as foreign key of ShowStatus.

```php
// ...
$model = 'App\Models\Event'; // or an instance of that model
$column = 'show_type_id';

$relatedModel = getRelatedModel($column, $model); // 'App\Models\ShowStatus' should be returned
```

Is there something in Laravel that can do that?

Comment: is it the answer to your question? `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26292718/laravel-get-class-name-of-related-model`

Comment: Nope sorry. Thanks for answering anyway :)

Comment: Maybe you need [Polymorphic Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships)?

Comment: @mare96 i'm not looking for that. What I want is to get the related model class by foreign key. thanks anyways :)