# How in laravel check var is collection of (Specific) models?

Tags: laravel

If there is a way to check in laravel 7 if given var is collection of (Specific) models?

I tried

```
gettype($collectionVar)
```

and it returns ‘object’ string value...

Thanks!

Comment: Possible values for the returned **gettype()** are:

`"boolean"`,
`"integer"`,
`"double"`, `"float"`,
`"string"`,
`"array"`,
`"object"`,
`"resource"`,
`"NULL"`,
`"unknown type"` . So Model instance and collection both give you gettype() as `"object"` is that case

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel get class name of related model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26292718/laravel-get-class-name-of-related-model)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the first Model in the collection and check the instance type

```
use App\Models\Specific

if ($collection->first() instanceof Specific) {
    // code here
}
```